# User Notifications in Laravel 4 App

Tags: notifications, laravel, laravel-4

In the event management app I am building I require user notification functionality. Having never implemented something like this before, I am after some advice on how you would go about doing this.

Here are a couple of scenarios that will require notifications.

**Scenario 1**:

Each event in the system has a start date associated with it. If the event also has delegates assigned to it that have a status of 'Provisional', I would like to send a notification 3 days before the event start date to any users with the role 'Admin', informing them that there are still provisional delegates assigned to this event.

**Scenario 2**:

There are accounts in the system, and each account has an account manager assigned to them. Accounts can also have multiple contacts associated with them. An account manager is able to assign a note to the account which is tied to a contact. So they can, for example, create a note of the type 'Scheduled Call'. The scheduled call has a date and time associated with it, so if around 1 day before I would like to send a notification to the account manager, informing them that they have a scheduled call due for this contact at the specified date and time. I'd like to keep sending or showing this notification until it is dismissed or deleted.

**Summary**:

There are several other scenarios but these 2 cover the basic functionality. I guess my question is this, has anyone implemented this or can anyone tell me how you would go about implementing such functionality in Laravel 4?

Specific questions are:

- Method of Implementation
- How to Automatically Check for these Specific Scenarios. Cron or via IronMQ or similar?
- Where to store the code. In a helper function or it's own controller?

Are there any other considerations I have missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need some sort of scheduled task / CRON job. Using the scheduled task, you can then run `php artisan YOUR_CUSTOM_COMMAND`. Obviously you would need to develop your own commands to use. See: http://laravel.com/docs/commands